# How can serialize html form to json object with multipe value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, typescript

I send my html values to server in below steps:

1. User submit form
2. In jquery i get user data
3. Convert it to object
4. Create jquery ajax data and object to it
5. Call ajax form

**Notice: I don't want to use jquery serialize because I need get some component like lookup that I created.**

My problem is complicated forms that contains multiple values. 
For example when I need a form that get uncertain numbers of user emails and so after it, add it object as an array.

```
<form>
    <input name="firstName">
    <input name="lastName">
    <input type="hidden" name="userId">
    <input type="checkbox" name="chkUserRole">
    <input type="checkbox" name="chkUserRole">
    <input type="checkbox" name="chkUserRole">
    <input type="checkbox" name="chkUserRole">
    <input name="userPhone">
    <input name="userPhone">
    <input name="userPhone">
    <input name="userPhone">
</form>
```

Result should be:

```
    {
        firstName:"",
        lastName:"",
        userId:"",
        chkUserRole:[],//items that are checked.
        userPhone:[],//it can be unlimited phone numbers that user can add field to form.
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```js
const form = $("#form");
form.on('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const requestData = {
    firstName: $("input[name='firstName']").val(),
    lastName: $("input[name='lastName']").val(),
    chkUserRole: [],
    userPhone: []
  };
  $.each($("input[name='chkUserRole']:checked"), function(){            
    requestData.chkUserRole.push($(this).val());
  });
  $.each($("input[name='userPhone']"), function(){            
    if($(this).val().length) {
      requestData.userPhone.push($(this).val());
    }
  });
  console.log(requestData);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form">
    <input name="firstName">
    <input name="lastName">
    <input type="hidden" name="userId">
    <input type="checkbox" name="chkUserRole" value=1>
    <input type="checkbox" name="chkUserRole" value=2>
    <input type="checkbox" name="chkUserRole" value=3>
    <input type="checkbox" name="chkUserRole" value=4>
    <input name="userPhone">
    <input name="userPhone">
    <input name="userPhone">
    <input name="userPhone">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the formData object:

```
var formElement = document.querySelector("form");
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("POST", "submitform.php");
request.send(new FormData(formElement));
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects